# PHP join two variable names

Tags: php, variables, dynamic-variables

I have a php script that gets a `$_POST` to decide which array to return. Ex:

```
$n = $_POST['n']; // 1, 2 or 3

$a1 = array ('something', 'something else', 'another thing');

$a2 = array ('something 2', 'something else 2', 'another thing 2');

$a3 = array ('something 3', 'something else 3', 'another thing 3');
```

now I want to get the array that corresponds to the `$n` value, let's say `"2"`.

How can I say `echo $a . $n` to get `$a2`

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`${'a'.$n}` gives you `$a2` if `$n` is `2`.

Answer (score 4):

It would be better that you make as this:

```
$a = array();

$a[1] = array('bla bla', 'bla bla');
$a[2] = array('asdasd', 'asdasd');
```

And then you can call as this:

```
echo $a[intval($n)]
```

Comment: +1 : use array to store a series of arrays is better than use few variables.