# Mysql query is not executing?

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to put an array of question into mysql table with having question1,question2,question3 upto 20 columns for each question but this query is not working please as :

the first query get successful but the second query is not working so please as :

```
$form_name = $_POST['form_name'];
$form_questions_no = $_POST['form_questions_no'];

$query_1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO forms (form_name,form_questions_no)
VALUES ('$form_name','$form_questions_no');") or die(mysqli_connect_error());

if ($query_1) {
echo "Form Name & Form Questions No Done.!</br></br>";
} 

$questions = $_POST['questions'];

for($i=0;$i<count($questions);$i++)
{

$query_text = "INSERT INTO forms (question$i)
VALUES ('$questions[$i]') WHERE form_name='$form_name'";

$query_2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"$query_text;") or die(mysqli_connect_error());

if ($query_2) {
echo "Question $i Done!";
}
}
```

so if you people can guide me please..I will be thankful for that..! I am beginner to PHP so that's why..!

Comment: Use arrays. Name the field as `question_no[]`

Comment: @arunrc : yeah..I know about that but really I want to Send this each field into different columns in a mysql database table so then how to send that array with into different columns please..! like I have columns for each question as `questions_no_1` in a questions table in mysql database so please..!

Comment: column for each question!! anyway you can save it using arrays itself. pls check my answer

Answer (score 2):

You want [**arrays**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)! Name your input fields as such:

```
<input name="questions[]" ...>
```

You'll then get an array in PHP:

```
$questions = $_POST['questions'];
```

You can loop through it:

```
foreach ($questions as $question) {
    echo $question;
}
```

Having dozens of individual variables named `$question_no_*` is pure madness.

Comment: @arunrc : yeah..I know about that but really I want to Send this each field into different columns in a mysql database table so then how to send that array with into different columns please..! like I have columns for each question as `questions_no_1` in a questions table in mysql database so please..!

Comment: That's also a terrible database structure. But even so, you do it the same way. Instead of `$question_no_1` you write `$questions[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

use forloop

```
for($i=0;$i<count($questions);$i++)
{
   echo $questions[$i]; //write your sql query here
}
```

fetching data from single column

```
$query="select question from table";
        $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo $row['question'];
        }
```

If you want it as question_no_1,question_no_2 etc.., then use below code

```
extract($_POST); //will give you $_POST['question_no..'] as $question_no_..
$fields_number = 5;
for ($x=0;$x < $fields_number;$x++) {

if (isset(${'question_no_'.$x++})) { 
$question_no_$x++ = ${'question_no_'.$x++}; 
} else { 
${'question_no_'.$x++}++ = ""; 
}

${'question_no_'.$x++} //this will give you $question_no_1, $question_no_2 etc..
```

[Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266754/php-join-two-variable-names) for joining two variables

}

Comment: Yes..thanks for it how can I generate inputs If I send all questions into one column it works like I SELECT * FROM questions table and then echo each array_name['columns']; so please?

Comment: I created columns like question1,question2,question3 upto 20 so can you update the question please for fetching data from these 20 columns and to put empty where columns in empty in 1 row just..!

Comment: Can you please take a look at my question back again..I updated it the query is not working..!

Comment: I have updated the question back again so please take a look at the question?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php 
$fields_number = 5; 
for ($x=0;$x < $fields_number;$x++){ 
    if (isset($_POST["question_no_$x"]))
    { 
        $question_no[$x] = $_POST["question_no_$x"]; 
    } else { 
        $question_no[$x] = ""; 
    } 
} 
print_r($question_no);

?>
```

Comment: I have just checked it back again it gives error as : `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$x' (T_VARIABLE) in D:\xampp\htdocs\php-login-new\admin\step_6.php on line 6`

Comment: Here it is as : `<?php


$fields_number = 5;
for ($x=0;$x < $fields_number;$x++){
    if (isset($_POST['question_no_$x'])) { $question_no_$x = $_POST['question_no_$x']; } else { $question_no_$x = ""; }
}

?>`